# What to say for opening and closing car widnow

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I've come across several ways of saying open or close **car window** with different comments on the appropriateness of each. Which is the most correct way of saying that, in the **casual street language**, out of the following: -

- Could you roll up/down your window
- Could you put up/down your window
- Could you let your window up/down
- Could you lower/raise your window
- or simply could you open/close/shut your window

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to come close to some kind of objective answer here is to refer to Google Ngram Viewer. It only shows what's relatively more common in print—but I know of no similar resource that has a database of what's common in speech.

---

For US English, it shows [the following](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=roll%20up%20your%20window%2Cput%20up%20your%20window%2Clet%20your%20window%20up%2Craise%20your%20window%2Copen%20your%20window&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croll%20up%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craise%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Croll%20up%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craise%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0) in descending order of commonality:

1. *open your window*
2. *roll up your window*
3. *raise your window*

Although *raise your window* is listed, it only has a single result, so it should be discounted. Neither *put up your window* nor *let your window up* produced any results at all.

[image: US open your window and variations]

---

Strangely, for UK English, [it shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=roll%20up%20your%20window%2Cput%20up%20your%20window%2Clet%20your%20window%20up%2Craise%20your%20window%2Copen%20your%20window&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Copen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bopen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOpen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Copen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bopen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOpen%20your%20window%3B%2Cc0) ***only*** *open your window*—and it lists it twice because of differences in capitalization.

[image: UK open your window and variations]

---

At least according to Google's collection of books in print, *open your window* is used more often by far than any of the other phrases. Since the opposite action will pair with these, I only looked at the *open* equivalents.

But I will add that this search is covering all types of windows, not just car windows. I tried the same query using *car window*, but got no hits of any kind. Since house windows are almost never ***rolled***, *roll* up or down could be a lot more common than is indicated here when it comes to discussing car windows specifically.

My personal experience matches that of the US results. (I'm Canadian, if that matters.) I only find the three phrases in the Ngram results to sound natural, and only *open* and *roll* what I would normally choose between.

Although I understand *put up your window* and *let your window up*, neither sounds natural to me, at least not outside of some contrived contexts. (Such as, in the case of *let your window up*, forcing a window down against a car's automatic attempts to raise it—and then letting it go.)

As for what would be common in "casual street language," I have no way of knowing. Anything I said would simply be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Roll up/down, put up/down, and open/close are all fairly colloquial in nature and relatively common. If I were asking someone to perform the function, or asking permission to perform the function myself, I'd most likely use roll or put. I've heard all three.

Raise/lower is more formal. If I were to write an instruction manual for a car, this is the term I'd use.

Let up/down sounds perhaps a bit regional.

Comment: I am in the US, and would not say "put up" or "put down".  But "roll up/down" and "open/close" are fine.

Comment: @GEdgar -- That's fine! The US is a big country, and there's bound to be considerable difference of usage.

Comment: From what I read on the internet there is controversy over using put up/down. It seems that it has other connotations in some areas with negative meaning, although I do not know what. Meanwhile, it seems that open/close and roll up/down, even for modern cars, are both accepted by everyone.